# Are high-end batteries (such as GS-Yuasa) worth their price compared to knock-offs?

Tags: motorcycle, battery

I am looking for a new battery for my motorcycle (Yamaha 600 TT RE)

To be precise, I am looking for a YT9B-4 battery.

I have been checking prices, and found out that the brand recommended by Yamaha Yuasa, is up to four times more expensive that knock-off brands.

Is there an actual difference, or am I just paying for the brand?

Comment: Quality is never cheap...

Comment: @SolarMike Sure, but there are cases where the products come out of the same plant, and just get a different brand name and twice the price. I would like to avoid falling for it

Comment: Don't forget to check warranty terms.  Some batteries may be made in the same factory but some will carry a 1 year replacement warranty whilst others carry a 4 year warranty.

Comment: @Maxime There are some that come out the back door for cash with no guarantee so you spend your money how you want - you don't have to accept my advice - I know which I purchased for my car...